# Disposing a Texture in LibGdx

Tags: libgdx

I am creating a single pixel with a specified color using a common method createSinglePixelTexture() as I have mentioned below.

**Question:**
1. Do I need to dispose "singlePixelPixmap" and texture "t" ?
2. If I need to dispose that where I can dispose it ?

```
singlePixelTexture = createSinglePixelTexture(0.129f, 0.129f, 0.129f, .7f);



private Texture createSinglePixelTexture(float r,float g,float b,float a) {
    Pixmap singlePixelPixmap; 
    singlePixelPixmap = new Pixmap(1, 1, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
    singlePixelPixmap.setColor(r, g, b, a);
    singlePixelPixmap.fill();
    PixmapTextureData textureData = new PixmapTextureData(singlePixelPixmap, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888, false, false, true);
    Texture t = new Texture(textureData);
    t.setFilter(TextureFilter.Nearest, TextureFilter.Nearest);
    return t; 
}
```

Comment: You have to dispose it! However, we can't tell you when you can dispose it. That's up to you... You dispose it, when it's not going to be used anymore.

Comment: But the variable "singlePixelPixmap" and " t" cannot be disposed as the scope is inside the method createSinglePixelTexture(). we cannot dispose it before the return statement. Any advice here

Comment: You have to dispose the texture out of this scope of course, since you return it. I think you can also make the pixmap "managed", which will cause it to be disposed as well when the texture gets disposed.

Comment: I am sure I have to dispose the texture "singlePixelTexture " which is out of scope of the method createSinglePixelTexture(). How about  "singlePixelPixmap" and " t" in createSinglePixelTexture(). Also Please let me know what is  pixmap "managed",

Comment: Looks like you are trying to solve the wrong problem. You really should reconsider your approach. Simple add an fully opaque white image of about 3 by 3 pixels (1 by 1 would also work, but it doesnt harm to expand it a bit) to your atlas. Then you can tint (e.g. `setColor`) that instead of creating a new texture each time.

Comment: I need the black pixel at a point and red and Green in another place. That's the reason behind this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You don't need the intermediary `PixmapTextureData`; it's entirely optional.
2. As soon as you create a `Texture` with a `Pixmap`, you can dispose the `Pixmap`. So you can insert the disposal of everything but the texture just before the `return`.
3. Once you dispose a `Texture`, it cannot be drawn. Do not dispose `t` unless you are SURE you will never try to draw it again.

Comment: I understand, could you please let me know where the dispose comes in  my method createSinglePixelTexture().